# PHP - Can't remove decimals when printing a number

Tags: php, decimal

in my app I have a table where I render some data. One of the table field renders a number, which is displayed like this: `8.300,0`.

This is the way I'm printing it:

```
<td class="ex"><span>< ?php echo round($value['data'][0]); ?></span></td>
```

I've tried with `number_format` function also, how can I get rid of the decimal part?

Thanks!

Comment: `(int)8.5455` will return `8` called typecasting use it

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Already tried, but nothing

Comment: Do you want to round it off in whole number?

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove, and what is the decimal? American/UK/International uses `,` as the thousands separator and `.` as decimal. European uses `.` as thousands and `,` for decimals. In other words, do you want `8.300` or `8`?

Comment: Does that comma appear or its just here???

Comment: @BenHillier I want 8.300

Comment: explode with delimiter `","` In programming number doesn't contain comma

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
<td class="ex"><span><?php list($number, $extra) = explode(',', '8.00,0');echo round($number); ?></span></td>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If you want decimal values as well then use round($number, $length), $length is number of digits you want after decimal.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

To round down:

```
echo floor($value['data'][0]);
```

To round up:

```
echo ceil($value['data'][0]);
```

To round off:

```
echo sprintf('%d', $value['data'][0]);
```

To get the result into European format, use the choosen function above and then:

```
number_format ( $result, 0 , ',' , '.' ); //Where $result is the result of the previous function.
```

Comment: Round doesn't round down. It round to the closest integrer.

Comment: @Ad5001Gameurcodeurautre. Thanks! I meant floor. Have updated accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your time!